# Does a daikaiju kill off a player if it appears next to them?

Tags: tsuro

According to the rules of [Tsuro of the Seas](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/124172/tsuro-seas), when a daikaiju *moves* adjacent to a player's ship, that player is eliminated. What if another player rolls a 6 to put a daikaiju on the board, and the square rolled is next to a player's ship? Is that player eliminated, or are they unaffected and have a chance for the daikaiju to move before their turn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The official rules](http://www.calliopegames.com/index.php?page=shop.getfile&file_id=68&product_id=77&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=) are maybe a little vague on the matter, but extrapolating from the context of the other rules, the way I have always interpreted them as is that a player is only eliminated if they are forced to move off the board, into a loop, or onto the same tile as a daikaiju - or, if it's their turn to play a wake tile but they cannot because there's a daikaiju directly in front of them. So my interpretation is that placing a daikaiju adjacent to some who is not the active player is the same as moving them to that space, and they are not eliminated.

Comment: "...placing a daikaiju adjacent to some who is not the active player is the same as moving them to that space, and **they are not eliminated.**" (Emphasis mine.) But the rules say (and I reiterated this in my question) that _moving a daikaiju adjacent to a player's ship eliminates them._

Comment: No it doesn't. To quote the rules: "If a daikaiju moves to a square adjacent to the active player's ship, that ship is destroyed [...] (the daikaiju prevents the player from placing a wake tile). If a second ship occupies the same side of the same wake tile [...] the second ship is not automatically destroyed [as] the daikaiju may move before that player's turn."

Comment: Perhaps it's a little unclear since it refers to moving adjacent to the active player, and then mentions also moving adjacent to a second player, rather than just saying "anyone who is not the active player".

Comment: Ah, I see. So if you're the active player, and a daikaiju is at any point put adjacent to you either by placement or by moving, you're out.  However, an inactive player that may be in the wake path next to you is not, since the daikaiju could move before their turn. The language is a little confusing.

Comment: Yeah. I think the easier way to think about it is not that putting the daikaiju next to you kills you, it's being unable to play a wake tile in front of you.